# c# linq selecting words that not start with

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

Consider these arrays:

```
string[] bad_starts = { "a", "b", "col" };
string[] word_list = { "green", "blue", "color", "cyan", "maroon", "white", "black" };
```

I need to select all the words in `word_list` that don't start with any string in `bad_starts`.
The expected result is:

```
{ "green", "cyan", "maroon", "white" };
```

Any solution? Could we use linq join?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try the following

```
var r = word_list.Where(x => !bad_starts.Any(b => x.StartsWith(b)));
```

Case insensitive version

```
var r = word_list.Where(x => 
  !bad_starts.Any(b => x.StartsWith(b, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)));
```

Comment: +1 You might want a case-insensitive comparison here.

Comment: @RedFilter added a version that ignores case

Answer (score 1):

You should try this:

```
var result = word_list.Where(x=>!bad_starts.Any(y => x.StartsWith(y))).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I like the 'Except' option

```
  var result = word_list.Except(word_list.Where(w => bad_starts.Any(b => w.StartsWith(b)))).ToList();
```

In the example I'm saying the following:

> - Select all words that starts with any character in bad_starts
> - Find all the words in word_list that contains these words
> - In the original 'word_list', exclude ('Except') all of these matches

So in plain English:
Select all words 'Except' the ones starting with specified characters

Another way of putting it is:

```
var bad_words = word_list.Where(w => bad_starts.Any(b => w.StartsWith(b));  
var result = word_list.Except(bad_words);
```

Comment: please give us some explanation to your answer